Google maps old JSon style targeting forrests
For context I am working on a .net MAUI app for iOS and Android using the Maui.GoogleMaps plugin, and need to style the default map to show forests clearly.
Using the "new" google maps styling on cloud platform, you can specify
natural, land cover, vegetation, forest
and set a color for that. In my case, I need to see them, now that the default style was changed to hide them.
I can do that and save a style, but unfortunately the API I am using to interact with google maps on a mobile platform only supports styling from json, and apparently there exist no json export.
The "old" google maps styling exported a json, which I can use, but it seems that I can only specify
natural, landcover
there, and am unable to target any specific type of vegetation.
I saw other people complaining (for years now) about not being able to export json from the "new" cloud platform styling, and mention a workaround where you would enter dev mode on the browser, observe network traffic, and catch the post to the server including the json, but that seems to have changed, since I see no such post on saving.
Is there a way to get a json style which specifically targets forrests?

There seems to be a related issue that was reported in Google's Issue Tracker. You can check the issue as all
publicly available updates will be posted there. Feel free to leave comments
on that bug as well for additional information.
